# Enable scrollbar after the timer

Tags: javascript

I would like to ask for a help regarding scrollbar. I have a project wherein there's a website intro. I would like to enable the scrollbar after the duration of the intro but I don't know how. Here is my code

```js
let intro = document.querySelector('.intro');
let logo = document.querySelector('.logo');
let logoSpan = document.querySelectorAll('.logo-parts');

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

  setTimeout(() => {
    logoSpan.forEach((span, index) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        span.classList.add('active');
      }, (index + 1) * 100);
    });

    setTimeout(() => {
      logoSpan.forEach((span, index) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          span.classList.remove('active');
          span.classList.add('fade');
        }, (span + 1) * 50);
      });
    }, 2500);

    setTimeout(() => {
      intro.style.top = '-100vh';
    }, 2500);

  });
});
```

```html
<div class="logo">Logo <span class="logo-parts">parts</span></div><div class="intro">Intro</div>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please add relevant HTML and CSS to make it a [mcve]. How is the scrollbar disabled for example

Comment: set ```overflow: hidden``` in your body css then on your time out set ```overflow: auto``` so that the scroll bar will be activated after a specified time.

Comment: Minor thing, but it doesn't make a lot of sense to have two 2500 timeouts set at the same time, the results could be combined in a single timeout. And your outermost timeout is missing a duration.

Comment: @DBS yeah 3 time outs with same duration dont give sense but i think you mean "inner most"

Comment: @seriously No, the first timeout, that wraps the others, is the one missing a specified duration (unless the indentation is wrong and I'm seeing things)

Comment: @DBS lol got it confused you are right :)

Comment: Thank you for taking your time checking my code. I will test it now. Apologies once more for the Post Format still noob.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let intro = document.querySelector('.intro');
let logo = document.querySelector('.logo');
let logoSpan = document.querySelectorAll('.logo-parts');

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  
  
  // I didn't touch this stuff:
  setTimeout(() => {
    logoSpan.forEach((span, index) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        span.classList.add('active');
      }, (index + 1) * 100);
    });

    setTimeout(() => {
      logoSpan.forEach((span, index) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          span.classList.remove('active');
          span.classList.add('fade');
        }, (span + 1) * 50);
      });
    }, 2500);

    setTimeout(() => {
      intro.style.top = '-100vh';
    }, 2500);
    
    // Here's what I added:
    document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
    setTimeout(() => {
      document.body.style.overflow = "";
    }, 2500);
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="logo">Logo <span class="logo-parts">parts</span></div>

<div class="intro">
  Intro
  <br><br> Dummy text so this works:
  <br><br> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi volutpat enim vitae sapien consequat tincidunt. Integer luctus maximus lacinia. Vivamus efficitur varius sagittis. In accumsan, augue nec imperdiet dignissim, lacus tellus tincidunt
  felis, non viverra erat magna rutrum libero. Nam ut vehicula lectus, sed bibendum sapien. Suspendisse pulvinar urna id euismod hendrerit. Aliquam id commodo neque, eget tempus justo. Donec pulvinar mi non nunc pretium tempus. Nunc vitae mauris non elit
  cursus rutrum vel ut eros. Vestibulum tempus enim lacus, nec finibus nunc dapibus at. Sed eu malesuada erat. Nulla posuere dolor at hendrerit sodales. Morbi ac urna et arcu egestas sollicitudin eget eget augue. In eget enim vestibulum augue malesuada
  lobortis. Fusce pretium tempor convallis. Proin in libero dolor. Quisque elementum enim neque, sed pharetra arcu rhoncus quis. Pellentesque at erat placerat, finibus ipsum eget, ultricies libero. Mauris dapibus scelerisque dignissim. Curabitur ultricies
  consectetur mi, ut ultricies lectus pulvinar in. Sed ut pretium dui, eget venenatis sem. Donec interdum urna id quam efficitur feugiat. Vivamus ultrices urna ut dui malesuada, et volutpat ipsum pulvinar. Mauris facilisis convallis magna id efficitur.
  Praesent condimentum nec felis nec facilisis. Phasellus in felis mattis, egestas justo eget, consequat sem. Sed blandit tempor porttitor. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Cras aliquam, nisl a tincidunt
  posuere, urna ex placerat nulla, sed gravida elit eros dignissim mauris. Aenean sed dolor at dui consequat placerat. Duis volutpat dolor et turpis accumsan ultricies. Vestibulum efficitur laoreet iaculis. Praesent varius dapibus augue, et laoreet nibh
  auctor eget. Suspendisse sit amet erat vestibulum mi ultricies sodales. Nam suscipit nisi non nulla pharetra ultrices. Phasellus tristique leo in metus varius, eget malesuada quam aliquam. Curabitur sollicitudin ornare magna ac rhoncus. Interdum et
  malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nam finibus commodo nunc commodo feugiat. Donec nisl elit, dictum facilisis ante sit amet, pretium egestas est. Duis et ornare nibh, id rhoncus felis. Vivamus vel ante vulputate, auctor velit ac, congue
  justo. Vivamus id varius dui. Nulla lectus eros, consequat sed diam non, molestie blandit dolor. Vivamus quis finibus tellus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi volutpat enim vitae sapien consequat tincidunt. Integer luctus
  maximus lacinia. Vivamus efficitur varius sagittis. In accumsan, augue nec imperdiet dignissim, lacus tellus tincidunt felis, non viverra erat magna rutrum libero. Nam ut vehicula lectus, sed bibendum sapien. Suspendisse pulvinar urna id euismod hendrerit.
  Aliquam id commodo neque, eget tempus justo. Donec pulvinar mi non nunc pretium tempus. Nunc vitae mauris non elit cursus rutrum vel ut eros. Vestibulum tempus enim lacus, nec finibus nunc dapibus at. Sed eu malesuada erat. Nulla posuere dolor at hendrerit
  sodales. Morbi ac urna et arcu egestas sollicitudin eget eget augue. In eget enim vestibulum augue malesuada lobortis. Fusce pretium tempor convallis. Proin in libero dolor. Quisque elementum enim neque, sed pharetra arcu rhoncus quis. Pellentesque
  at erat placerat, finibus ipsum eget, ultricies libero. Mauris dapibus scelerisque dignissim. Curabitur ultricies consectetur mi, ut ultricies lectus pulvinar in. Sed ut pretium dui, eget venenatis sem. Donec interdum urna id quam efficitur feugiat.
  Vivamus ultrices urna ut dui malesuada, et volutpat ipsum pulvinar. Mauris facilisis convallis magna id efficitur. Praesent condimentum nec felis nec facilisis. Phasellus in felis mattis, egestas justo eget, consequat sem. Sed blandit tempor porttitor.
  Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Cras aliquam, nisl a tincidunt posuere, urna ex placerat nulla, sed gravida elit eros dignissim mauris. Aenean sed dolor at dui consequat placerat. Duis volutpat
  dolor et turpis accumsan ultricies. Vestibulum efficitur laoreet iaculis. Praesent varius dapibus augue, et laoreet nibh auctor eget. Suspendisse sit amet erat vestibulum mi ultricies sodales. Nam suscipit nisi non nulla pharetra ultrices. Phasellus
  tristique leo in metus varius, eget malesuada quam aliquam. Curabitur sollicitudin ornare magna ac rhoncus. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nam finibus commodo nunc commodo feugiat. Donec nisl elit, dictum facilisis ante
  sit amet, pretium egestas est. Duis et ornare nibh, id rhoncus felis. Vivamus vel ante vulputate, auctor velit ac, congue justo. Vivamus id varius dui. Nulla lectus eros, consequat sed diam non, molestie blandit dolor. Vivamus quis finibus tellus.
</div>
```